# what is the tenant name for the Office Video connector in Microsoft flow?

Tags: office365, power-automate

For example, if the sites if https://example.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx, I figured the tenant name would be exmample.com but that didnt work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this what your after? https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Office-365-videos-connection/td-p/29926

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  I was able to use the API to get the channel id and the video id without a problem.